# Listing entry showing same article no matter what url is using template routing

Tags: channel-entries, template-routes, listing

I have a listing entries template set up that is using routes (not even sure that's the issue), but same article on listing entry page no matter what the url is. What am I missing?

Set up a template route:

[image]

Here are the entry listings:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news_entry" dynamic="off" limit="15" paginate="bottom"}
    <h2><a href="{route='news/news-entry' title='{url_title}'}">{title}</a></h2>
    <time><strong>Published: {entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</strong></time>
    {exp:streeng words="100"}{news_content}{/exp:streeng}
    <a href="{route='news/news-entry' title='{url_title}'}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">...Read More</a>
    <hr>

    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And here's the single listing where it's showing same article no mater what url is:

```
{embed="layouts/index"}

{!-- PAGE CONTENT --}
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="news_entry" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment:title}"}

        {stash:content}

            <main id="main">
                {if page_banner}
                <section class="banner-section" style="background-image:url({page_banner_background_image});">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="banner" style="background-image:url({page_banner});"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                {/if}
                <section class="twocolumns">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                <aside id="sidebar">
                                    <a class="nav-opener" href="#">Side Menu</a>
                                    {sidebar_nav}
                                </aside>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="text-block breadcrumbs-container">
                                            <span class="breadcrumbs">
                                                {exp:low_variables:pair var="news_breadcrumb"}
                                                    <a href="{news_breadcrumb:path}">{news_breadcrumb:page_name}</a> >
                                                {/exp:low_variables:pair}
                                                <span class="last">{title}</span>
                                            </span>
                                            <h1 class="heading">{title}</h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-block">
                                    <div class="info-area add news-entries">
                                        <h2>{title}</h2>
                                        <time><strong>Published: {entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</strong></time>
                                        {news_content}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>

        {/stash:content}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: In the detail template, what tag is this `url_title="{segment:title}"` ? A plugin or something custom ?

Comment: I figured it out...was as simple as updating structure url in listing in backend. I removed that from channel tag.

Comment: In future, you may want to add ALL the modules in play.